# EF: select all entities of subclass (inheritance)

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, database-first, table-per-hierarchy

I am using the Database first approach and DbContext. 
I have several inheritance structures (TPH) in my data model. 
But DbContext only creates one DbSet for the base class, and none for the subclasses. 
How should I retrieve all Entities of a specified subclass?

I cannot write queries based on the mapping criteria, as i had to remove those fields from the data model.

Can I simply add a new DbSet to the Entities class (partial class) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add new properties returning `DbSet`s of your derived types into context's partial class or you can simply use `OfType<DerivedType>()` operator when querying sets created by the code generator.