# I need subclass fields with SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I use EF 6. I have a product base class. I use SqlQuery but i need subclass fields too. How can i do that?

```
public class Product{
    public int ProdId{get;set;}
    public string ProdName{get;set;}
}

public MySubProd1:Product{
    public string MySubProd1{get;set;}
}

public MySubProd2:Product{
     public string MySubProd2{get;set;}
}

    public DbRawSqlQuery<Product> GetSql(int prodId,string[] fields)
    {

        var sql = "SELECT {0} FROM Products WHERE ProdId={1}";
        //i need here MySubProd1, MySubProd2 fields too
        return _db
                .Database
                .SqlQuery<Product>(sql, String.Join(",", fields), prodId);

    }
```

Comment: Well, find out the name of the subclass field --probably "discriminator" if you have TPH inheritance. But why do you use a SQL query, not a `DbSet` and LINQ?

Comment: how can i get subclass's fields with linq? if you show me a way i can use it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10697145/861716

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want, but be aware that there is no class in your model that can capture all properties in the `Product` class hierarchy. Meaning: you can't convert `SELECT * FROM Products` into `Product` objects.

Comment: sure. you are right.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping you would take on the "not entirely clear to me what you want" part.

Answer (score 0):

With EF, you simply do this:

```
var query = from p in context.Products.OfType<MySubProd2>() select p;
```

Please see [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) article for details on how to structure you model to allow you to do that.

Comment: @GertArnold well it was not meant to compile with the ellipsis. The idea is to use `OfType<T>` and also to model as per the article in the link.

Comment: @GertArnold ok got it. Edited the code. I should have put the ellipsis in a different place. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: First, TPH is not the only EF inheritance setup that allows polymorphic queries. Second, OP is not asking how to load specific derived class, but how to load all derived class data.

Comment: i have multiple sub class and i have to use multiple oftype<t>. i 've tried it but i can select just one (at last) sub class's properties.

Comment: @IvanStoev I never made the claim TPH is the only EF inheritance setup; even the article I linked discusses both of them. To your second point, if `Employee` inherits `Person`, when you do `context.Persons.OfType<Employee>()` will get you all the properties of `Person` and `Employee`. I am pretty confident that is the case but if you think not, please let me know.

Comment: @Yargicx see my comment to IvanStoev. If you do `OfType<X>` then it will have all the properties of type `X` and properties of the type it inherits in the hierarchy.